# Button over JS onClick or modal toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that toggles a modal. I am doing it by either using the built in data-toggle function or the onClick method. Now i want to have a button inside this div that calls a ajax request and does not open the modal.

How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using the stopPropogation() method:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-3" data-target="#modal-1" onclick="toggle_modal(this)">
    <div id="1" onclick="toggle_start(this)></div>
</div>

function toggle_modal(clicked_element){
    id = $(clicked_element).attr('data-target');
    $(id).modal('show');
}

function toggle_start(clicked_element){
    alert($(clicked_element).attr('id'));
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return **false** in the button click event listener, here is a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8jskff0r/):

```
$('#ajax').click(function(e){        
    alert('do ajax');
    return false;
})
```